# Huge excel table - sorting into other excel automaticaly

Tags: excel

[What i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyO5X.png)

I'm not too sure how to formulate my question so here it goes.

I am helping with a big 20k+ rows excel spreadsheet, that has data sorted by ID. What I want to do is sort that data by company name and export to another excel file.

What I would like to know is - what are the best methods to do that with least manual job, sounds weird, however I am helping my fathers friend and he does this manually every quarter.

My idea of doing this is by importing that spreadsheet into database and then exporting it as I like, however I feel that there is more simple way of doing that.

Comment: 'export to another excel file.' Why not simply make a copy, the sorting is a standard feature in Excel which can be done by anyone.... 

Comment: Do Excel Macros suffice your requirement? What is your Excel version? If you can record an Excel macro, you can simply open the excel and invoke your recorded macro with a Shortcut key. This does not require programming knowledge at least for your requirement.

Comment: You should be able to do this easily with VBA. Just loop through the records on the sheet and match company name to populate each company sheet. You can also use the database method like you mentioned but that would involve another application that the end user may have to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question: 20,000 rows in really not that much (the maximum is about one million), and as far as sorting is concerned, I've made a small screenshot of how to sort an Excel table, based on company value and ID (sorry for the Dutch language), you might record this and turn it into a VBA macro:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Is this what you are looking for or do you need extra information?

Comment: No the sorting by itself is not the problem, the real problem is : lets say i need only one company records and put them in another excel file

Comment: As far as filtering is concerned, there are two possibilities : either you just want to filter the data from one particular company. This can be done using the standard filtering feature. In case you want to automate this for every company, you might need to automate filtering using VBA.